# Which python api for facebook graph video uploads to a fan page?

Tags: python, facebook, video, facebook-graph-api

I need to upload videos to a facebook fan page from a python webapp.

At the beginning of this year I tried using the rest api, but it wasn't supported.  However, it appears that this is now possible (where have I been?) using the graph api: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/515/#%E2%80%9Dapp_page_video_upload%E2%80%9D

Are there any python packages that can do this currently?  I've browsed through github but on first glance I didn't see support.

Here are the packages I've found that seem somewhat active:

https://github.com/feinheit/django-facebook-graph

https://github.com/iplatform/pyFaceGraph

https://github.com/facebook/python-sdk

Comment: Seems like nobody uses the facebook graph api with python =/